# unknown input using apply function in r

Tags: r, apply

I want to implement a function to every column of a matrix x.

However, the matrix x is the output of another apply function in a for loop.

`x=apply(y,2,function(x) approx(...))`

In some cases, the approx function will return only one value. Then,  the output x will be a 1*1000 vector. Then the apply function of x will fail.
I try to use as.matrix function, but it will turn the vector to 1000*1.

The only way I think is use if statement to see dim(x) is null or not.
If dim(x) is null then the x is 1*1000 and I will write another few lines to deal with the vector case. If dim(x) is not null the apply function will work well.

Is there any better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why would `dim(x)`be null if x is a 1*1000 matrix ? Is it a 1-column matrix or a vector ?

Comment: In returning your matrix result you are probably performing some form of slicing `m[i, j]`, which then transforms your matrix into a vector when the dimension is 1. In slicing use `drop=FALSE` and you will always be getting a mtrix back, even if the dimension is 1, e.g. `m[i, j, drop=FALSE]`. In this way you will tackle the cause of your problem with apply, not the symptomps

Comment: @Vincent x is the result of a apply function, x=apply(y, 2, function(x) approx(...)) the approx function sometimes return only one value so the apply will return a vector, which is x.

Comment: @OlegS. thank you for your answer. but the x is the result of a apply function, sometimes it return a vector...does apply function also has some parameters like `drop=FALSE` can force the result to be a matrix

Comment: You can use `t(x)` and then apply if the dim is null.  There's unfortunately not a `simplify=FALSE` option to apply that stops the helpful but sometimes annoying feature you've discovered.  Even `y <- array(as.vector(y), c(ncol(y), nrow(y), 1))` followed by `apply(y, c(2,3), ...` will give differently shaped results depending on whether approx returns a scalar or vector.

Comment: @GavinKelly Thank you! I think t(x) will fix this problem with only few more lines of code.

Comment: @Louisyan If you think you have a solution, can you post it as an answer and accept it to close out this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I didn't following the way Gavin Kelly suggested in the comment, which is using t(x).
I use

```
if (is.null(dim(X)){(the special case if X is a vector)}else{(the regular way}
```

to fix this problem. It looks a bit clumsy but it works at last..
Any better solution is welcomed :)